# bevel on edge is not as expected

Tags: modeling, bevel

i modeled this mesh and wanted to bevel a line of edges but it looks weird and not right:
[image]

Anyone knows what went wrong? Here is the model:
[image]

Comment: cannot retrieve your blend file at https://file.io/dprwWdjsCApm please upload again at https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: You can share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it. At the moment I suspect that your file will have been deleted from the site where you uploaded it as soon as it's been downloaded.

Comment: Hi and sorry for the wrong link, i hope this is right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverted normals on your object. To see them, enable <kbd>Face Orientation</kbd> on the <kbd>Viewport >Overlays</kbd> dropdown.

[image]

Go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode, select <kbd>A</kbd>ll and then <kbd>Shift-N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.

On the Bevel modifier, increase the <kbd>Bevel</kbd><kbd>Amount</kbd> to .001 or so and uncheck <kbd>Clamp Overlap</kbd> in the <kbd>Geometry</kbd> section of the modifier.

[image]

Comment: A big thank you John for the awsome explanation with the great pictures! I would never have solved that problem on my own. Thanks for your hard work that solved my Problem!

Comment: @Terrain No problem. Please check my answer as accepted.